# TYPO3 extensions/plugins creating <p> tags in HTML pages

Tags: html, plugins, typo3, fluid

I created an extension and plugin using extension builder which generates some HTML code to a file `fileadmin/templates/List.html`.This content goes into my web page's template.html as

```
<f:section name="some-content">
<f:format.html> {some_content} </f:format.html> 
</f:section>
```

some_content comes from my Typoscript template

```
some_content < styles.content.get
some_content.select.where = colPos = 1
```

The plugin is attached from a backend layout

The problem is that in my HTML page I get plugin information in `<p>` tags

```
<p class="bodytext">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="bodytext">    <!--  CONTENT ELEMENT, uid:260/list [begin] --></p>
<p class="bodytext">&nbsp;</p><div id="c260" class="csc-default"><p class="bodytext">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="bodytext">        <!--  Plugin inserted: [begin] --></p>
<p class="bodytext">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="bodytext">        <!--  Plugin inserted: [end] --></p>
<p class="bodytext">&nbsp;</p></div><p class="bodytext">    <!--  CONTENT ELEMENT, uid:260/list [end] --></p>
<p class="bodytext">&nbsp;</p>
```

And this messing up my CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<f:format.html>` uses RTEparser to parse the content in it. Each new line will be wrapped with a `p`-tag.

Use `<f:format.raw>` to avoid HTML escaping.

Comment: Wont this effect my HTML tags in the page ? I haven't tried `<f:format.raw>` yet though.

Comment: nice to hear that :)

Answer (score 2):

add following lines in template script of root

In Constants :

```
content.RTE_compliant = 0
```

In Setup :

```
tt_content.stdWrap.dataWrap >
lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines>
```

Comment: it works for me with only `lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines >`

Answer (score 2):

As you want to use `<f:format.html>` i would prefer to still use it, but with its parseFunc attribute.

```
<f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="">{some_content}</f:format.html>
```

There you can assign the parse functionality. (An empty value ignores the standard behaviour and the default display of P tags.

Comment: thanks matox, this one worked the best, without editing any ts

Comment: with `parseFuncTSPath=""`, links like t3:// are not replaced.